# VB.net DomainUpDown Infinite Selection

Tags: vb.net

How can I get a DomainUpDown in vb.net to go from: `DEFAULT then FLAT then LARGEBIOMES then AMPLIFIED then CUSTOMIZED then back to DEFAULT and so on`? Like an infinite Selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [the `.Wrap` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown.wrap.aspx):

```
upDownControl.Wrap = True
```